# Ember-Router: How to add a route in run-time in Ember 1.0-rc2?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In the *new* `Ember.Router` that shipts with Ember 1.0-rc2, is it possible add route in run-time?

Comment: Check out the edit that I just added, it gives you a solution that will drop in and work

Answer (score 4):

There is not a supported method of doing this currently. The `App.Router.map` call is handled by lines 235-247 of this code: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js

```
Ember.Router.reopenClass({
    map: function(callback) {
        var router = this.router = new Router();

        var dsl = Ember.RouterDSL.map(function() {
          this.resource('application', { path: "/" }, function() {
             callback.call(this);
          }) 
        });

        router.map(dsl.generate());
        return router;
    }
```

The map is overwritten every time you call `Router.map` as the callback for the previous call to `Router.map` is not persisted.

**Edit**
For better or worse, I've got a pull request in to alter the behavior to allow multiple calls to `App.Router.map`. We'll see what happens. You can follow here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2485

**Another Edit**

I've written a gist to do what my pull request does in userland. This will let you map routes at runtime. Just add this code and then replace your calls to `App.Router.map` with the method that I've defined

https://gist.github.com/grep-awesome/5406461

**Answer Changing Edit**

As of this pull request, you may now call `map` multiple times. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2892

Answer (score 1):

I see that wmarbut's answer hasn't been accepted, but it is a good one (for me).  It seems that his patch is on its way into the Ember release, but until then this is some code that uses his patch.  (Don't accept my answer, I'm just happy to have found this.)  I'm planning to use it as part of a solution to let content drive navigation.  Good question, user1517325 and **thanks, wmarbut!**

```
  // was an all-in-one router map as Ember likes it
  // App.Router.map(function() {
  //   this.resource("foods", function(){
  //     this.route("index", {path: "/"});
  //   });
  //   this.route("fourOhFour", { path: "*:"});
  // });

  //wmarbut's workaround until his patch is applied
  App.map_routes = [];

  App.MapRoutes = function(routes) {
      App.map_routes.push(routes);
      return App.Router.map(function() {
        var route_lamda, _i, _len, _ref;
        _ref = App.map_routes;
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          route_lamda = _ref[_i];
          route_lamda.call(this);
        }
        return true;
      });
  };

  //partial mapping
  App.MapRoutes(function() {
    this.resource("foods", function(){
    });
  });

  //some more mapping
  App.MapRoutes(function() {
    this.resource("foods", function(){
      this.route("index", {path: "/"});
    });
  });

  //even more mapping
  App.MapRoutes(function() {
    this.route("fourOhFour", { path: "*:"});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest release ember.js **rc7** it was added the functionality to the `Router.map` to allow it to be called multiple times without the map being overwritten. This will allow routes to be added at runtime.

Hope it helps.