# How do I add or change routes on runtime in ember (ember-cli)

Tags: ember.js, routes, router, ember-cli

I'm building an application with `ember-cli` and want be able to change a route on runtime. Say we have the following router defined:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('me');
  this.route('users', function() {
    this.route('user', {path:'/user_id'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

After authentication, I want to change the path of the `me` route into the authenticated users id (or slug):

```
this.route('me', path:'/6');
```

This way I can have my navigation, including proper active states, like so:

```
{{link-to "me"}}Me{{/link-to}}
{{link-to "users"}}Users{{/link-to}}
```

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16046975/1790950) that you can run `router.map()` multiple times without overwriting previous routes but I can't figure out how the subsequent map call is made from another module than `router.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would **highly** recommend against this. Not only is it probably not supported by Ember and likely to cause a ton of issues, but there are many ways to handle this situation without dynamically altering the route structure.

That being said, you can call `map()` from another module as you would from within the router module, just import the router first. As an example, if you were going to do it in the `afterModel` hook:

```
import Router from '../router';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.getAndAuthenticateUser();
    },
    afterModel: function() {
        Router.map(function() {
            this.route('newlyDefinedRoute');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does exactly what I wanted to try. I'm well aware it is somewhat hacky. I'd be better for future reference to elaborate a bit more on why you think this is an unrecommended/unsupported method though, and what would be a better direction (The alternative would be to hack into the `linkView`, right). I think [this pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2892) by was in part created to be able to do things like this.

Comment: Without getting too much into the details, having dynamic routes means ensuring that you never reference those routes when they haven't been created yet. I can see it quickly turning into dependency hell. If I were doing this, I would just have two different routes: one for when the user is authenticated and one for when the user isn't. You can redirect between the two based on your authentication state.